# Physical interpretation of the asymptotics of partition function in string theory

Tags: string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, partition-function, large-n

I would like to understand the physical interpretation of the asymptotic expansion of a partition function. The QCD partition function with gauge group $SU(N)$ as $N$ is large has been shown by Gross and Taylor to be interpreted as the partition function of a 2-dimensional string theory. They showed that it can be written as a sum over maps from a 2d world-sheet to a 2d target space.
Could you explain me what does the $1/N^k$ term mean physically?